# SQL: Filter by count in a table with NO primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, primary-key

In a table which looks like::

```
  name    |    posts    |  comments
---------------------------------------
user1     |  page1      |  90
user1     |  page2      |  50
user1     |  page3      |  40
user2     |  page2      |  55
user2     |  page4      |  45
.         |  .          |  .
.         |  .          |  .
.         |  .          |  .
```

What's the best way to, for example, find the users which have more than 2 posts?

The way I'd normally do this is to group by using the primary key,

```
(for example) SELECT * FROM table
              GROUP BY PrimaryKey
              HAVING COUNT(name) > 2
```

But can't do this in this case;; what's a way to proceed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: `normally do this is to group by using the primary key` and `GROUP BY PrimaryKey` Are you aware that PK is unique so you don't get any duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want this:

```
SELECT user_name
FROM table
GROUP BY user_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

You seem to have a misunderstanding of what a primary key is.  Your version of the query will return no rows.  Why not?  A primary key is *unique*.  There are no duplicates.  You want duplicates by `user_name`, so this seems like the appropriate query.